# How do I write different log entries to two different log files using java.util.logging?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

Is it possible to write different information to two different log files using java.util.logging?  I was able to create two different log files, but they both contain the same entries.  I don't create my Logger as static.  I'm basically have my own logging class and I am instantiating it twice for the two different loggers, but again, the same information is being written to both the files.

Answer (score 0):

Add two [FileHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)s to your logger.

```
final Logger logger = Logger.getRootLogger();

FileHandler handler1 = new FileHandler("foo");
FileHandler handler2 = new FileHandler("bar");

logger.addHandler(handler1);
logger.addHandler(handler1);
```

Also see [LogManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).

FYI: [Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) has much better configuration options. That's what most people use.

Comment: That's what I basically did.  I just created my own logging class where I do the new FileHandler and addHandler.  Then I instantiate my logging class twice where I pass it a different filename as part of the constructor.  Still logs the same information to both logfiles.

Comment: 1. You don't need to instantiate your logger twice if it has both appenders.

Comment: 2. You have to configure each file handler if you want them to have different output.

Comment: “That's what most people use.” Do you have any non-anecdotal data to back that up?

Comment: @VGR "most popular picks are Logback, which is an evolved version of Log4j, Log4j itself, and its new version... Log4j2" http://blog.takipi.com/is-standard-java-logging-dead-log4j-vs-log4j2-vs-logback-vs-java-util-logging/

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all handlers from the root logger after you've setup your two customer loggers.

```
final Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
for (Handler h: rootLogger.getHandlers())
    rootLogger.removeHandler(h);
```

Your customer handers are probably not configured properly and everything is going to your root logger.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to write different information to two different log files using java.util.logging?

Yes. You have to either attach the handlers to different locations in the logger tree if you want to capture information about siblings.  An example `logging.properties` would look like:

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=some%u.log
my.app.feature1.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
my.app.feature1.useParentHandlers=false
my.app.feature2.handlers=java.util.logging.FileHandler
my.app.feature2.useParentHandlers=false
```

If you need to divide the logs by [level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Level.html) or [filter by some other custom property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Filter.html) then you should use the [LogManager `config` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html).
Per the documentation:

> A property "config". This property is intended to allow arbitrary configuration code to be run. The property defines a whitespace or comma separated list of class names. A new instance will be created for each named class. The default constructor of each class may execute arbitrary code to update the logging configuration, such as setting logger levels, adding handlers, adding filters, etc.

An example class would be:

```
package com.app.config;

import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Filter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public final class ErrorAndInfoHandlers {

    /**
     * Don't allow G.C. to remove our settings.
     */
    private static final Logger[] PIN = new Logger[]{
        Logger.getLogger("app.feature"),
        Logger.getLogger("app.system")
    };

    public ErrorAndInfoHandlers() throws Throwable {
        installSystem();
        installApp();
    }

    private void installSystem() throws Throwable {
        FileHandler h = new FileHandler();
        h.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        h.setFilter(new LessThanFilter(Level.INFO));
        Logger.getLogger("app.system").addHandler(h);
    }

    private void installApp() throws Throwable {
        FileHandler h = new FileHandler();
        h.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        Logger.getLogger("app.feature").addHandler(h);
    }

    private static class LessThanFilter implements Filter {

        private final Level upper;

        LessThanFilter(final Level upper) {
            this.upper = upper;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLoggable(LogRecord record) {
            return record.getLevel().intValue() < upper.intValue();
        }
    }
}
```